# port open but getting connection refused ...centos 8 / nginx / react / nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, centos, connection-refused

**I have nodejs running on pm2 and its listening on port 5000**. If i run  `netstat -na |grep 5000` on the server i get

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

But when my react app makes a call to `http://localhost:5000/patients` i get

`::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

**Here is the code for the server:**

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use('/patients', require("./routes/patientRoute"));


app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port: ${port}`);
})
```

**and from React production build i run GET with axios to** `http://localhost:5000/patients` thats when the err occurs

**Also i have opened the port on firewalld**

Comment: The could be an selinux issue.

Comment: i ran setenforce 0 ...it did nothing still

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get any chance to solve it?

Comment: @MarcoGazzin yes, first i had to get rid of the "0.0.0.0", then i added /api/ to the beginning of all of my axios calls and then in my nginx conf file i needed to add 
````location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  }````.....the location block in NGINX was the key!

Answer (score 2):

first i had to get rid of the "0.0.0.0", then i replaced `http://localhost:5000` with `/api/` on all of my axios calls and then in my nginx conf file i needed to add location
`/api/ {     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;   }`
.....the location block in NGINX was the key!